# sendmail: proper /dev/urandom

Tags: sendmail

I'm configuring sendmail on hpux 11.31 
i have to set a a random file
if i set

```
define(`confRAND_FILE',`dev:/dev/urandom')dnl
```

Give this error

```
STARTTLS: Error: no proper random file definition dev:/dev/urandom
```

if i set

```
define(`confRAND_FILE',`file:/dev/urandom')dnl
```

Give this error

```
STARTTLS: Warning: safeopen(/dev/urandom) failed
```

How to set?
Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put in the version of HP-UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found
http://support.hp.com/id-en/document/c00916394

Must use egd:/dev/urandom,not file,using /dev/random give an error

Here's the correct mc file

```
divert(0)dnl
VERSIONID(`$Id: generic-hpux10.mc,v 8.13 2001/05/29 17:29:52 ca Exp $')
OSTYPE(hpux11)dnl
DOMAIN(generic)dnl
define(`_X400_UUCP_')dnl
define(`_MASQUERADE_ENVELOPE_')dnl
define(`MASQUERADE_NAME')dnl
define(`confTRY_NULL_MX_LIST',`T')dnl
define(`LUSER_RELAY',`name_of_luser_relay')dnl
define(`DATABASE_MAP_TYPE',`dbm')dnl
define(`_CLASS_U_')dnl
define(`LOCAL_RELAY')dnl
define(`MAIL_HUB')dnl
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5')dnl
FEATURE(always_add_domain)dnl
MAILER(local)dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(openmail)dnl
MAILER(uucp)dnl
define(`SMART_HOST', `posta.domain.com')
define(`confCACERT_PATH', `/etc/mail/certs')dnl
define(`confCACERT', `/etc/mail/certs/domain.com.crt')dnl
define(`confSERVER_CERT', `/etc/mail/certs/hpux2.domain.com.crt')dnl
define(`confSERVER_KEY', `/etc/mail/certs/hpux2.domain.com.key')dnl
define(`confCLIENT_CERT', `/etc/mail/certs/hpux2.domain.com.crt')dnl
define(`confCLIENT_KEY', `/etc/mail/certs/hpux2.domain.com.key')dnl
define(`confRAND_FILE',`egd:/dev/urandom')dnl
D{tls_version}TLSv1
O UseTLS=True
```

Answer (score -1):

Get random package from [here](https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=KRNG11I)

As far as I remember HP-UX do not provide /dev/random or /dev/udandom devices

Comment: Old version don't provide it,i'm on 11.31

Comment: Have you try to use /dev/random? Do you have openssl installed?

Comment: Openssl installed,i will try /dev/random this evening

Comment: no way STARTTLS: Warning: safeopen(/dev/random) failed

Comment: This is why I asked for the version number first.